# Strange number on Massachusetts Form 1-NR/PY

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, massachusetts

I see the following:

[image]

Referring to line **3**, I understand I have to divide the total days as Massachusetts resident with 365 and carry the division to four decimal places. This is explained nicely in the guide. But why is there a `3` after the equals sign where it says `÷ 365 = 3`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is just showing (awkwardly, I admit) that the result of this calculation is the value for line 3, and not the 'total days as Massachusetts resident'. You can see this elsewhere on the form, e.g. line 27:

[image: Line 27]

Comment: Wow; that's stupid. Why not put a prefix or something, like `x .12 = L27`? Or `L.27`?

Comment: I think it would better to put it to the right of the result box, marked separatedly (for example, with brackets "(27)"